# Global modal react redux\toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have an application with react-redux/toolkit and I have two types of modal, one for confirmation and another in which I manage the state throughout redux store, but I can't pass it a component to render because non-serializable values are not allowed in redux store.

How can I make a single component through redux store, to manage all my modals?